# Display an awesome wm cheatsheet when holding down the Windows key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, awesome

In Unity if you hold down the Windows key for long enough a cheat sheet is displayed on the screen for how to use the keyboard with Unity.  Is there a similar key for Awesome VM?

Comment: Maybe you could use this https://github.com/cmichi/awesome-cheatsheet/blob/master/awesome.pdf

Comment: @M.Becerra Thank you, I'm aware of that file, but it works alot better when it is easily and quickly displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is already in the default config of awesome 4.2:

If you press **Mod-l** you get an overview over the *hotkeys*. The same menu is accessible through the awesome menu at the top left corner of the screen.

However take note that awesome undergoes huge changes from versions 3.4 to 3.5 and also from 3.5 to 4.x so you might have an older version which doesn't contain this feature.

If you really want it to be on the Windows Key you would have to change your modkey to Alt by changing `modkey=Mod4` to `modkey=Mod1` and then editing your key bindings

from:

```
globalkeys = gears.table.join(
awful.key({ modkey,           }, "s",      hotkeys_popup.show_help,
              {description="show help", group="awesome"}),
```

to

```
globalkeys = gears.table.join(
awful.key({            }, Mod4,      hotkeys_popup.show_help,
              {description="show help", group="awesome"}),
```